###"Uncaught Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize') when using react-native-openai"
###I am developing a React Native application and I am encountering the following error when trying to initialize the OpenAI object from the react-native-openai library:
Verify
Open In Editor
Edit
Copy code
Uncaught Error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize')
Call Stack
OpenAI#constructor
node_modules/react-native-openai/lib/module/index.js
useMemo$argument_0
app/(auth)/(drawer)/(chat)/new.tsx
...
import HeaderDropDown from '@/components/HeaderDropDown';
import MessageIdeas from '@/components/MessageIdeas';
import MessageInput from '@/components/MessageInput';
import { defaultStyles } from '@/constants/Style';
import { Message, Role } from '@/utils/Interfaces';
import { Storage } from '@/utils/Storage';
import { useAuth } from '@clerk/clerk-expo';
import { FlashList } from '@shopify/flash-list';
import { Redirect, Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { useState, useMemo, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useMMKVString } from 'react-native-mmkv';
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  Button, 
  KeyboardAvoidingView, 
  Platform, StyleSheet, 
  Image 
} from 'react-native';
import OpenAI from 'react-native-openai';


const DUMMY_MESSAGES: Message[] = [
  {
    content: 'Hello, how can I help you today?',
    role: Role.Bot,
  },
  {
    content: 'I need help with my react native app , I need help with my react native app,I need help with my react native app, I need help with my react native app, I need help with my react native app, I need help with my react native app, I need help with my react native app, I need help with my react native app , I need help with my react native app, I need help with my react native app',
    role: Role.User,
  },
]

const Page = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const [key, setKey] = useMMKVString('apiKey', Storage);
  const [organization, setOrganization] = useMMKVString('org', Storage);
  const [gptVersion, setGptVersion] = useMMKVString('gptVersion', Storage);

  if (!key || key === '' || !organization || organization === '') {
    return <Redirect href={'/(auth)/(modal)/settings'} />;
  }

  const openAI = useMemo(
    () =>
      new OpenAI({
        apiKey: key,
        organization,
      }),
    [key, organization]
  );

  console.log('OpenAI instance:', openAI);  
  

  const getCompletion = async (message: string) => {
      console.log('Getting completion for:', message);
      if (messages.length === 0) {
        // Create chat, latter, store to db
      }

      setMessages([
        ...messages, 
        { content: message, role: Role.User },
        { role: Role.Bot, content: ''},
      ]);
  
      openAI.chat.stream({
        messages: [
          {
            role: 'user',
            content: message,
          },
        ],
        model: gptVersion === '4' ? 'gpt-4' : 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = (payload: any) => {
      console.log('Received message:', payload);
      setMessages((messages) => {
        const newMessage = payload.choices[0].delta.content;
        if (newMessage) {
          messages [messages.length - 1].content += newMessage;
          return [...messages];
        }

        if (payload.choices[0]?.finishReason) {
          // save the message  to DB
          console.log('Stream ended');
        }

        return messages;
      });
    };

    openAI.chat.addListener('onChatMessageReceived', handleMessage);

    return () => {
      openAI.chat.removeListener('onChatMessageReceived');
    };
  }, [openAI]);

  const onLayout = (event: any) => {
    const { height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setHeight(height);
  };

  return ( 
    <View style={defaultStyles.pageContainer}>
      <Stack.Screen
      options={{
        headerTitle: () => 
        <HeaderDropDown 
        title="ChatGPT"
        onSelect={(key) =>{
          setGptVersion(key);
        }}
        selected={gptVersion} 
        items={[
          { key: '3.5', title: 'GPT-3.5', icon: 'bolt'},
          { key: '4', title: 'GPT-4', icon: 'sparkles'},
        ]}
        />,
        
      }}
      />

      <View style={{flex: 1}} onLayout={onLayout}>
       {messages.length === 0 && (
        <View style={[styles.logoContainer,{marginTop: height / 2-100}]}>
          <Image source={require('@/assets/images/logo-white.png')} style={styles.image} />
          </View>
       )}
       <FlashList
       data={messages}
       renderItem={({item }) => <ChatMessage {...item} />}
       estimatedItemSize={400}
       contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingBottom: 150,
        paddingTop: 30,
       }}
       keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
       />

      </View>

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
      keyboardVerticalOffset={70}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        padding: 16,
      }}
      behavior={Platform.OS ===  'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
        {messages.length === 0 && <MessageIdeas onSelectCard={getCompletion}/>}
        <MessageInput onShouldSend={getCompletion} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logoContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor:  '#000',
    borderRadius: 50,

  
  },
  image: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  }
})
export default Page; ```

What could be causing this error?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to properly initialize OpenAI?
Is there an alternative way to handle this initialization to avoid this error?
Thank you for any help or suggestions!

